# svg rect renders good in chrome and ie but bad in firefox and opera

Tags: firefox, svg, opera

this very simple svg renders very well in chrome 30 and ie 9. but the rectangle get cutted to a bad size in firefox 25 or opera 12

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="svg_treemap">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)" class="items_node">
    <rect x="0" y="0" style="fill: rgb(0, 255, 255);" height="445" width="835"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
```

any ideas?

Comment: [ not connected to this question, but you may wish to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20067103 ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing width and height attributes on the `<svg>` element. Try width="100%" height="100%".

I'm afraid neither IE nor Chrome implement this properly but Chrome at least has plans to do so.

Comment: omg ... these are the situations when i hate web developent :-)