# Update MySQL table with CSV data containing literal values in an unsupported format

Tags: mysql, csv, yahoo-finance

Someone recently deleted a question that I thought could be quite helpful to the community.  I paraphrase:

> I am obtaining a CSV file from the Yahoo! Finance API, with which I then wish to update the following MySQL table:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE yahoo.static (
>   symbol         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>   exchange       VARCHAR(200),
>   name           VARCHAR(300),
>   capitalization DOUBLE,
>   div_pay_date   DATE,
>   book_value     DOUBLE,
>   float_shares   BIGINT UNSIGNED,
>   PRIMARY KEY (symbol)
> );
> ```
>
> The CSV file has the following format:
>
> ```
> "AAUKF","AAUKF","Other OTC","AAUKF","ANGLO AMERICAN OR","AAUKF",29.271B,"AAUKF","26-Apr-12","AAUKF",26.69,"AAUKF",  1134107000
> ```
>
> Particular problems include:
>
> - repeated, superfluous values;
> - suffixes (e.g. `K`, `M` and `B`) that indicate order of magnitude; and
> - dates not formatted in a supported literal format.
>
> How can I update the table from such a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) command, one can assign columns to user variables and then perform appropriate operations accordingly:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/ystaticB.csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE yahoo.static
    CHARACTER SET utf8              -- or however the file is encoded
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  -- quotes appear to be optional
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'        -- or however newlines are encoded
    (symbol,@z,exchange,@z,name,@z,@c,@z,@d,@z,book_value,@z,float_shares)
    SET
        capitalization = @c * POW(10, CASE RIGHT(@c,1)
                           WHEN 'K' THEN 3
                           WHEN 'M' THEN 6
                           WHEN 'B' THEN 9
                         END),
        div_pay_date   = STR_TO_DATE(@d, '%e-%b-%y')
```