# convert datetime format from csv to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am exporting data from csv where datetime is in the format

```
20/02/2012 16:42:10,
```

and mysql table date format like

```
2013-11-04 10:00:52

but after exporting it is displayed like this
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Full CODE after edited

```
// MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data source = ; database = ;uid= ;pwd=faithful ;Convert Zero Datetime=true;");
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data source =; database =;uid=root ;pwd=H0tjava1;Convert Zero Datetime=true;");

        DataTable db = new DataTable();


        string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'I:/kiran/final test/finaltest12.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,@VarDateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes) SET DateTime  =  STR_TO_DATE(@VarDateTime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');";
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(strLoadData, conn);


        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;


        cmd1.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd1.Prepare();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

error

```
Fatal error encountered during command execution. at this line cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: In your MySQL table, I'd expect it to be a datetime field, which doesn't logically *have* a format - it's just a date and time value, which can be formatted any way you want.

Comment: See [Update MySQL table with CSV data containing literal values in an unsupported format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20067104).

Answer (score 3):

Try like below

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'F:/Explor/final test/finaltest12.csv' 
INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(SiteId,@VarDateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes)
SET DateTime  =  STR_TO_DATE(@VarDateTime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Here `DateTime` is the Name of column.

Comment: Don't just provide code, point the OP to documentation. E.g. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html especially sections describing the effect of use of the `SET` clause within `LOAD DATA`

Comment: I get this error when i try this code.. Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: It might be because i have some null values

Comment: hi when i tried this code  i am getting @LastpaidDate paramter must be defined error